# How to Store and Load a BOOL array or int Array with NSUserDefaults? (iOS7)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, nsuserdefaults

I'm building an iOS game app and I'm basically trying to store in `NSUserDefaults` a BOOL array of levels (to see which level is unlocked) and an int array that stores the number of points the player earned in each level.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store Booleans in an array like this:

```
NSArray *boolArray = @[@YES,@NO,@YES];
```

And Integers like this:

```
NSArray *intArray = @[@1,@2,@3];
```

You can then save your array to NSUserDefaults (although I really don't recommend doing that) like this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:boolArray forKey:@"myBoolArray"];
```

And you can later retrieve it like this:

```
NSArray *retrievedArray = (NSArray *)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myBoolArray"];
```

Comment: Thank You! But why wouldn't you recommend doing that?? Is there a beetter way?

Comment: Because if the user resets its settings, your data will be gone. A better way would be a plist if you need that data persisted.